# Cannot download softwares from the Software Center

Tags: 11.10, software-center, package-management, dependencies, downloads

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my computer that has Windows7 on it as well.
I was first trying to upload Chromium and I got this error:

> **Package dependencies cannot be resolved**
>
> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time

This came up when I was trying to download Chromium, Skype and VLC, though there was no problem downloading Geany or 7zip.

Once again, I haven't done anything before on Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There might be updates pending that need to be installed before installing software. Make sure that your software sources are updated.

To update your system press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> while in your desktop and look for ***update-manager***

[image]

Press <kbd>Check</kbd> and after it is finished press <kbd>Install Updates</kbd>.

Has an option you can open a terminal and do the same with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. This is preferable since if you get any errors you can copy them and include them in your question.

To open a terminal just press the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> while in your desktop.

Reboot to be sure and try to install the software again.